# Result in simple html dom doesn't match result in browser

Tags: html, parsing, dom, prestashop

I try to search the max ammount of quantity I can add to cart.
So I change in every url the parametre **qty=**

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com/en/cart?add=1&id_product=26&qty=1&token=8b003fa01d462f09e0de452c19193175");
echo $html;
```

-

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com/en/cart?add=1&id_product=26&qty=3&token=8b003fa01d462f09e0de452c19193175");
echo $html;
```

But in the echoed $html I get **always 1 product was added to the cart** even if I change qty=.

However If I dow it manually in my browser: If i visit "http://example.com/en/cart?add=1&id_product=26&qty=3&token=8b003fa01d462f09e0de452c19193175" I get **3 products was added to the cart**.

Answer (score 0):

It is your code which runs at example.com ?

1 I am almost sure that, for security issues, there is more than this simple URL.

2 generally, there is another id, on your computer: check cookies in your browser. You certainly will find something in relation with token.

3 programs can also check wich browser is visiting them. shopping servers dont like robots.

4 to get the same behaviour with your app, you should at least:

- manage cookies as a browser;
- perhaps change type of client, to spoof a browser;
- and perhaps simulate an entire connection (with login): see next point.

5 last: have you tried another token ? what happen ?  It is sure it keeps you from your login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no it's not my website, I'm tring to parse this particular content max quantity, you can try change example to "luxor".ma"